# Powershell not sending email sometime

Tags: email, powershell

I have some PS Scripts which is executed as follows:

Script1: Executed only once and it stores the entered password as a secure string in a text file

Script2: Executed repeatedly as a scheduled task. This invokes another script - Script3.

Script3: Every time, this script works fine for it's main task. But it has a mail sending feature which everytime gets failed. The script is as shown below:

```
$time = (Get-Date).ToShortTimeString()
$destzone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time")
$desttime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeFromUtc((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime(), $destzone)
$desttime = $desttime.ToShortTimeString()
if($time -eq $desttime)
{
#do nothing
}
else
{
***Main Function of script***
#E-mail Function
#Getting Credential from txt file

$passw = Get-Content C:\timezone\mailcred.txt | convertto-securestring
$crede = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "user@domain.in",($passw)

#Mail Function
$param = @{
SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com'
Port = 587
UseSsl = $true
Credential  = $crede
From = 'user@domain.in'
To = 'user@domain.in'
Subject = 'Alert - Timezone changed'
Body = "Time zone changed to Central Standard Time for system with IP $ip"
}
Send-MailMessage @param
}
```

The errors which I recieve is:

```
Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "password" is null. Change the value of argument "password" to a non-null value."

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Credential'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

While executing the same mail function script alone, it works fine. But executing along with other script block is not working.

Comment: Can you look for the scheduled task in the taskscheduler (microsoft -> windows -> powershell) and look for the credentials the task is running with? Try adding credentials in the taskrunner (default running with no special rights). Adding credentials when you add the job is some more powershell work, first test if it will help.

Comment: @WalterA: I am running it manually. but that time also its not working.

Comment: Look for the line which gives problems, using the powershell ise as administrator. Does `$passw = Get-Content C:\timezone\mailcred.txt | convertto-securestring` work? Does `$passw = ConvertTo-SecureString -string "myPassword" -asplaintext -force` work?

Comment: Nothing works. I just displayed value of $passw and it showed m System.SecureString . Plain text wont work as I am storing it in encrypted form rather than plain text.

Comment: Are you using the same credentials to run Script1 that your using to run Script3?

Comment: @mjolinor: Each system has different passwords.

And I found out the issue. I was creating a session before this and I am trying to pull out that file remotely. That was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me for the credentials

```
# Create PSCredential
    $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
    $secstr = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force

    $credentials = New-Object -Typename   System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "user", $secstr
```

Comment: Thanks. But I already resolved the issue. Can you help me on this?
http://serverfault.com/questions/688362/variable-values-to-pass-from-local-computer-to-remote-in-pssession

What I need is I am creating a session with the remote host. I am able to disconnect to the session, but then PS never comes back to the local computer session.

Comment: $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $myComputer -Credential $credentials

      # powershell syntax requires -Scriptblock and { on this line
      Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
       param([string] $processName)
                Get-Process -Name $processName } -Args $processName

 Remove-PSSession $session